# How do you remove numbers greater than or equal to a specified number within a list, in python

Tags: python, error-handling, index-error

So the goal is to take integer inputs, use the first number to tell how many integers are actually on the list, and the last number is the range (so in this case its 100, so everything greater than or equal to 100 on the list should get removed in the print)

*Also both the first and last numbers should be removed in the final statement*

This is what I could come up with but I encountered two problems: In the first half, it removes everything like its supposed to except the '3000', it seems like its just the element in the list thats not getting removed because, '140' and '100' both get removed like theyre supposed to.

The second problem is in the print statement at the bottom, im not entirely sure why but, its giving "IndexError: list index out of range"

USER INPUT EX.: 5
50
60
140
3000
75
100

```
numbers = []
integers = int(input())
while True:
    integers = int(input())
    numbers.append(integers)
    firsti = numbers[0]
    if len(numbers) > firsti + 1:     #if the number of items in list (numbers) > the first list item PLUS ONE
        numbers.remove(numbers[0])    #remove the first item
        lastdigi = numbers[-1]
        for number in numbers:    
            if number >= lastdigi:    #removes all numbers >= last digi
                numbers.remove(number) 
        break                         #and prints the rest
    
listnum = len(numbers)                #this whole section is to try and print the numbers from the list
while listnum >= 0:                                                       #and match the example output
    print (numbers[0], end=',')
    numbers.remove(numbers[0])

print(numbers)
#example output: '50,60,75,'
#my output: '50,60,3000,75,'
```

Comment: You wrote that the *last* number is the range. But you're using the second number as the range.

Comment: Can you not use a comprehension to eliminate values above a certain number? i.e. `numbers = [x for x in numbers if x < value]` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution.
The problem is when you used remove() the list lost part of its index.

```py
numbers=[5, 50 ,60, 140 ,3000 ,75, 100]
#integers = int(input())
while True:
 #   integers = int(input())
  #  numbers.append(integers)
    firsti = numbers[0]
    if len(numbers) > firsti + 1:     #if the number of items in list (numbers) > the first list item PLUS ONE
        numbers.remove(numbers[0])    #remove the first item
        lastdigi = numbers[-1]
        new_list = []
        for number in numbers:
            if number < lastdigi:    #removes all numbers >= last digi
                new_list.append(number) # [HERE] you are loosing the index
        break                         #and prints the rest

# this whole section is to try and print the numbers from the list
for i in new_list:                                                      #and match the example output
    print (i, end=',')

print(new_list)
```

I made some modifications.

Answer (score 0):

You're not using the `integers` variable that specifies the number of inputs to use.

`firsti` is the first input after that, but you're using it as both the number of inputs and also as the limit. But the limit is supposed to be the *last* input after the 5 numbers.

You can use a list comprehension to remove all the numbers that are above the limit.

```
integers = int(input())
numbers = [int(input()) for _ in range(integers)]
limit = int(input())

result = [x for x in numbers if x < limit]
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

As with most puzzles in Python-- list comprehensions tend to help a lot, here's an example that I think mostly adheres to the rules you set:

```
data_in = '5 50 60 140 3000 75 100'

# Try cleaning the user input first, turning it to integers:
try:
    values = [int(x) for x in data_in.split()]
except ValueError:
    print("Only integers expected")

# Check rules set are adhered to:
# in theory could user input could at min be two integers "0 100"
if len(values) < 2:
    raise ValueError('Need to at minimum specify a length and max value')
elif len(values) - 2 != values[0]:
    raise ValueError('First value should be count of expected ints')

# remove first and last entry-- then filter based on last value.
results = [x for x in values[1:-1] if x < values[-1]]

# Pretty the output with commas:
print(",".join([str(x) for x in results]))
```